# Override expand/collapse animation in panel/grid with EXTJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Normally, the expand/collapse functionality in extjs works as the panel/grid header stays in a position and the body of the panel/grid moves down/up. But I need the panel header to be in a position and on expand, the header has to move up showing the panel/grid body. On collapse, the header has to move down and come to the original position. This is just like expand and collapse in accordian layout inner panel. But I want it with a single panel. Any code samples or pointer would be very helpful.

Note: Please note that I cannot use any third party plugin..

Comment: which version of extjs are you using?

Comment: Extjs version is 4.2.1 and please note that the functionality has to work in browsers >= IE7

Comment: Why don't you use an accordion layout with only one panel?

Answer (score 2):

This sample in ExtJs 4.2.1.

One way to do what you are trying to achieve is by injecting "expander" *div* in *afterrender* event of parent panel before collapsible children. This means items are at the bottom of parent body after expander *div* so there is space to expand them up. When children are collapsed/expanded or parent is resized, injected *div* gets height of parent minus children.

You can see it here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/44c

Edit: I don't really get 1 panel part - if you want single panel to behave like that, expander could be injected into wrapper before header and content, but than you are left with panel of same size but collapsed - the only scenario this makes sense to me is by reversing collapse of children in sample I provided

Comment: Hi..Thanks a lot for the Answer. Will try it out and will let you know the result..